# Multiple: Computers - Operating Systems - Backup

Tags: windows, backup, images

I manage a laboratory with computer driven instruments. These computers use varying operating systems from Windows 7 to 10 including XP and possibly 95. I have a need to back up both the data and programs, basically image the hard drive of each computer.  I am searching for how best to proceed across the multiple platforms. These computers are not networked. Suggestions?

Comment: Software recommendation requests are off topic here.

Comment: Thank you. I should rephrase to suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Rather than "tell me what software to use" you should tell us what you have tried so far and what didn't work. Explain why what you tried doesn't suit your needs and ask if there is a way to fix it. If people tell you to use a tool that's fine, but we want to focus on fixing a problem you actually have trouble implementing rather than just "I don't have software."

Comment: If all you are doing is looking for software to solve a problem then it might be worth asking at [softwarerecs.se] but you would need to clearly define your requirements and read their [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: A way is to convert all to VMS , then the VM manager does it.  This is the way one lab I saw had done it. Except for the lab machines with special hardware , hence I don't propose this as an answer, but it might save you some work down time.

Comment: I think you did edit but it still is not clear what you have tried. Can you reboot each machine to a dish imaging software disk? Cam you install different versions of imaging software on each machine? can you network them? (no from the question) can you turn them into VMs?

Comment: There are backup programs and systems that do this. Having a single product solution may not be possible, but it may be, and only research with knowledge of your environment will answer this. If you need image backups, this constrains your options, and may not work over the network. Dealing with PLCs and equipment controller computers in the past, I kept HDDs with copied of the production machine drives in storage for quick swaps with minimal downtime.

Answer (score 1):

Use an Ubuntu Live USB and use the `dd` utility to image the source drive to another drive or as an image file to be stored elsewhere.

Comment: Or rescue media (CD or USB drive) from any imaging software, such as Macrium reflect, Aomei Bakupper., etc. **N.B.** If these are 32-bit systems, e.g., 95, you'll likely need 32-bit software to run on those PC's. Make **two** rescue media, one 64-bit and one 32-bit.

Comment: I think you boot from the rescue software disk so it does not need to match the PC bitness.

Comment: @Ross, if the PC is 32-bit, it cannot run 64-bit software.

Comment: Oh hardware , yeah you are right

Answer (score 0):

Clonezilla

Make a bootable clonezilla thumb drive.
Get an external USB hard drive.

Plug external hdd (or sdd if you have the money) into PC.
Plug USB stick into PC

Turn on, and press whatever the boot from USB options is, HP its mostly F9.

Select the options "device to image" and save the image to your external storage.  Older PC with USB 2 maybe slow, but it will get the job done.